# qbXML C# and ReckonAccounts australia

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbxml

I am developing a winform(C#) application for on premise version of Reckon Accounts Enterprise Profession Service 2013 for an Australian firm.
Reckon is installed on the same server where this application will run
Please can somebody tell me

- Is the quickbook and reckon API are one and the same or different.
- What do I need to install on my server to connect to Reckon and fire qbXML queries.

I have tried to do the following
I have added reference to QBSDKComUtil 1.0 Type Library
I have added reference to QBXMLRP2 1.0 Type Library
My .Net version is 4.0

```
using QBXMLRP2Lib;

 private string ticket;
        private RequestProcessor2 rp;
        private string maxVersion;
        private string companyFile = "";
        private QBFileMode mode = QBFileMode.qbFileOpenDoNotCare;

        private static string appID = "";
        private static string appName = "ReckonConnector";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rp = new RequestProcessor2();
            //RequestProcessor2Class.
            rp.OpenConnection2(appID, appName,QBXMLRP2Lib.QBXMLRPConnectionType.localQBDLaunchUI);
            ticket = rp.BeginSession(companyFile, mode);
            string[] versions = (string[])rp.get_QBXMLVersionsForSession(ticket);
            maxVersion = versions[versions.Length - 1];
            MessageBox.Show(maxVersion);
        }
```

This is the error I recieve
Message "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {45F5708E-3B43-4FA8-BE7E-A5F1849214CB} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

Could you please clarify as to what I am doing wrong and is the Reckon API different from Quickbook api?

Comment: Hello I want to some discuss with you regarding to Reckon Account Hosted API is you have any Idea so please contact to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your application for target x86 only and NOT all cpus.